# Python h5py installation problems

Tags: python, pip, h5py

I'm attempting to follow this project: https://github.com/MasazI/cnn_depth_tensorflow

The issue is I don't have h5py. So I do pip install h5py. Then I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert_mat_to_img.py", line 4, in <module>
    import h5py
ImportError: No module named h5py
MBP-R-006:cnn_depth_tensorflow-master admin2$ pip install h5py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==10.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 480, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2691, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2322, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2328, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 626, in <module>
    _handlers = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()  #map of handler names to handlers
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 55, in __init__
    def remove(wr, selfref=ref(self), _atomic_removal=_remove_dead_weakref):
NameError: global name '_remove_dead_weakref' is not defined
```

Is my version of python on my OS X messed up/needing modifications? How can I fix this?

EDIT:

I just typed 'pip -V' and this is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==10.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 480, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2691, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2322, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2328, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 626, in <module>
    _handlers = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()  #map of handler names to handlers
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 55, in __init__
    def remove(wr, selfref=ref(self), _atomic_removal=_remove_dead_weakref):
NameError: global name '_remove_dead_weakref' is not defined
```

Comment: Your python installation is broken, this has nothing to do with h5py or with machine learning.

Comment: Partly unrelated: I have using homebrew's version, after running into problems with the native version (I cannot remember what kind of problems though).